Microphones, both built-in and external not working
Im using a HP Laptop 14-em0033nf running Arch Linux on Hyprland.
No matter if i'm trying to use the built-in mic or an external one, i cant get any sound out of them. I know the hardware is not at fault, since it works on Windows.
The problem is probably not the DE, since a default Ubuntu setup on GNOME has the same problem.
If anyone knows how to fix this, i'd be really thankful.
